# Docker image failed with caniuse-lite is outdated error

Tags: docker, yarnpkg, caniuse

Failed to create an image on the staging server with the below error.

> Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run next command `yarn upgrade caniuse-lite browserslist`

Here is my package.json

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --host=0.0.0.0 --content-base=public",
    "jest": "jest --no-cache --runInBand",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "test": "yarn lint && yarn flow && yarn jest",
    "fix": "eslint . --fix"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.1.6",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-json-strings": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-import-meta": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.6",
    "@babel/preset-flow": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.4",
    "bluebird": "^3.5.3",
    "circle-to-polygon": "^1.0.2",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "color-rgba": "^2.1.0",
    "css-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "eskape": "^1.2.0",
    "flow-bin": "^0.89.0",
    "flow-typed": "^2.5.1",
    "fuse.js": "^3.4.2",
    "highcharts": "^7.0.0",
    "highcharts-react-official": "^2.0.0",
    "informed": "^1.10.12",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "mapbox-gl": "^0.53.0-beta.1",
    "mixpanel-browser": "^2.26.0",
    "moment": "^2.23.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "normalize.css": "^8.0.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "react": "^16.6.3",
    "react-aria-menubutton": "^6.1.0",
    "react-color": "^2.17.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.6.3",
    "react-ga": "^2.5.6",
    "react-helmet": "^5.2.0",
    "react-map-gl": "^4.0.8",
    "react-portal": "^4.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-table": "^6.8.6",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.7",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "svg-react-loader": "^0.4.6",
    "uid-safe": "^2.1.5",
    "webpack": "^4.26.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.10",
    "yaml-loader": "^0.5.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "babel-jest": "^23.6.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.8.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.7.1",
    "eslint": "^5.9.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^3.3.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^12.0.0",
    "eslint-config-standard-react": "^7.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^22.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^8.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.11.1",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^4.0.0",
    "expect": "^23.6.0",
    "file-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
    "jest": "^23.6.0",
    "lodash-match-pattern": "^2.0.1",
    "prettier": "^1.15.2",
    "sinon": "^7.2.2",
    "yaml-jest": "^1.0.5"
  },
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "private": true
}
```

[image]
I am new to docker and don't know how to resolve this error.

The project is on Reactjs, recently I have updated the node-saas version to 4.14.1 and after that, I am facing this error.

Comment: When you run `yarn run webpack` in your own machine, do you get the same error?

Comment: Yes, My image is broken on that command. `RUN yarn run webpack`

Comment: If you are getting the same error when you running on your local machine, then, it might be easy to resolve this issue while not building the image.